# Handling the python twitter api data with either csv or json

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv, pandas, tweepy

I am streaming the data and the data is being saved into a json file like this

```
 with open('filename.json', 'a') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Now I want to read the data for further analysis. To simply use the json file  in another program what the simplest thing I could do is.

```
import json
with open('D:\Devotion of time\Data\paralympics.json') as f:
data= json.load(f) 
or 
data= json.loads(f.read())
```

In Both cases I am getting the below error:-

```
c:\python27\lib\json\__init__.pyc in load(fp, encoding, cls, object_hook,                      
parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
276         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
277         parse_constant=parse_constant,                                         
object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook,
278         **kw)
279 
280 

c:\python27\lib\json\__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook,    
parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
324             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
325             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not 
 kw):
326         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
327     if cls is None:
328         cls = JSONDecoder

c:\python27\lib\json\decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
367         end = _w(s, end).end()
368         if end != len(s):
369             raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
370         return obj
371 

ValueError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 - line 107 column 1 (char 13127 - 394133)
```

If I am switching to something else like this

```
data = []
with open('file') as f:
for line in f:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Then I am getting **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'**
also sometime  **ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded**

I searched for solution but nothing help.
I also tried to read it with **Pandas** (pd.read_json()) but same issue.

*What I want to do with data, is to change into a csv file or if it is json , so try to somehow use it easily. Data look like [this](http://pastebin.com/pZYPAGGe)

so How to deal with this ? should I change the program or something else? Or any better suggestion to deal with twitter data.*

Working with Python27, win10, tweepy.

Answer (score 1):

Your file does not contain a single JSON object but several JSON objects in each line. You can parse each line as follows:

```
with open('t.txt', 'r') as f:
    res = []
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() != '':  # The sample file also has empty lines
            res.append(json.loads(line))
```